# C++ accessing element in vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

I'm trying to access an element within a vector of class objects but I don't get it right. I guess it's something wrong with the constructor/deconstructor and reference but even the other questions like [C++ destructor issue with std::vector of class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745350/c-destructor-issue-with-stdvector-of-class-objects), [c++ vector of class object pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798631/c-vector-of-class-object-pointers) or [C++ vector of objects vs. vector of pointers to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624819/c-vector-of-objects-vs-vector-of-pointers-to-objects). Hopefully someone can help me to fix my code snippet.

### node.h

```
class Node {

public:
    Node();
    Node(int id, const std::string& name);
    Node(const Node& orig);
    virtual ~Node();

    void cout(void);

    int get_id(void);

private:
    int _id;
    std::string _name;

};
```

### node.cpp

```
#include "node.h"

Node::Node() {
}

Node::Node(int id, const std::string& name) : _id(id), _name(name) {
    this->cout();
}

Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
}

Node::~Node() {
}

void Node::cout(void) {
    std::cout << "NODE " << _id << " \"" << _name << "\"" std::endl;
}

int Node::get_id(void) {
    return _id;
}
```

### communication.h

```
#include "node.h"

class Com {

public:
    std::vector<Node> nodes;

    Com();
    com(const Com& orig);
    virtual ~Com();

    void cout_nodes(void);

private:

};
```

### communication.cpp

```
#include "communication.h"

Com::Com() {
    nodes.push_back(Node(169, "Node #1"));
    nodes.push_back(Node(170, "Node #2"));
}

Com::Com(const Com& orig) {
}

Com::~Com() {
}

void Com::cout_nodes(void) {
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
        nodes[i].cout();
    }
}
```

If I run `Com com;` I get the expected output of:

```
[I 171218 13:10:10 Cpp:22] < NODE 169 "Node #1"
[I 171218 13:10:10 Cpp:22] < NODE 170 "Node #2"
```

but running `com.cout_nodes();` results in:

```
[I 171218 13:10:14 Cpp:22] < NODE 0 ""
[I 171218 13:10:14 Cpp:22] < NODE 0 ""
```

As in [C++ vector of objects vs. vector of pointers to objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624819/c-vector-of-objects-vs-vector-of-pointers-to-objects) everything works fine when I use references but I couldn't get `std::iterator` and `find_if` working than.

#### update: working `find_if` statement and index calculation

```
auto iterator = std::find_if(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), [&](Node node) {
    return node.get_id() == 169;
});

if (iterator != nodes.end()) {
    size_t index = std::distance(nodes.begin(), iterator );
    std::cout << "Index of ID #169: " << index << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You defined this copy constructor:

```
Node::Node(const Node& orig) {
}
```

And it doesn't do any copying. It default initializes all the members of the `Node` being constructed. Since `std::vector::push_back` does a copy of its argument, your get bogus copies.

Rather than forcibly define an operation which the compiler can just as easily synthesize correctly by itself (you only have an `int` and a `std::string` as members), just don't declare it.

Or, if you do want to be explicit (or need to be, such as with the default c'tor), just explicitly default it:

```
class Node {

    Node()                 = default;
    Node(const Node& orig) = default;

};
```